# jquery dialog not appearing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span that I want to create a jquery dialog on when it is clicked.

I have included this in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#quote_dialog').click(function () {
        $('#quote_dialog_open').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The following is the span (havent included content):

```
<span id="quote_dialog">
    content
</span>
```

And the div is just a box on the screen:

```
<div id="quote_dialog_open">
    content
</div>
```

I assume I need to hide the div using CSS? Will jQuery make it popup as opposed to just appearing?

Nothing is happening at present when the span is clicked.

Comment: Which plugin are you using? jQuery doesn't have a `.dialog()` method out of the box. Can you create a demo, or at least show a complete example (full HTML including libraries you've loaded)? Are there errors in the JS error console?

Comment: Have you loaded jqueryUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Make sure you are also including the relevant jquery UI...

Secondly, look at this fiddle, it shows you the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // next add the onclick handler
  $("#quote_dialog").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    return false;
  });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0nzhtLw/

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

wild guess, your problem is the typo, change

```
$('#quote_dialog_oepn').dialog('open');
```

to

```
$('#quote_dialog_open').dialog('open');
```

Comment: The typo was a mistake as I typed the question! It isn't the reason!

Comment: do you get errors in the console, describe the problem you encounter